# AWS PutItem not creating entries in DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to write a lambda function which writes an array of strings to a generic collection where the Primary key is the type of a collection. It should always replace the current item (if exists, otherwise create one) with a new one.

This is my handler function

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context) (Response, error) {
    item := lib.SkillsCollection{
        Collection: lib.SkillsCollectionName,
        Value: lib.Skills{
            "test",
            "test 2",
        },
    }

    log.Printf("Prepare item %v", item)

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))
    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)

    log.Printf("Created session")

    av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Marshall error mapping value %s", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Marshalled item %v", av)

    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String(lib.DbCollectionsTable),
        Item:      av,
    }

    log.Println("Start scanning collections")

    _, err = svc.PutItem(input)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error during put %v", err)
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer

    body, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
    })
    if err != nil {
        return Response{StatusCode: 404}, err
    }
    json.HTMLEscape(&buf, body)

    resp := Response{
        StatusCode:      200,
        IsBase64Encoded: false,
        Body:            buf.String(),
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    }

    return resp, nil
}
```

According to the logs everything is OK. No errors are thrown and I get response with status 200

These are the logs
[image]

However, after that I don't see any items in the DynamoDB table. It's empty. I can't figure out where to look for the root of the issue. At the same time I can see that there were writes to the table.

[image]

I've already rewritten the solution to follow the example in the AWS docs but no luck with that.

The struct in case it matters

```
type Skills []string

type SkillsCollection struct {
    Collection string `dynamodbav:"collection" json:"collection"`
    Value      Skills `dynamodbav:"value" json:"value"`
}
```

And the DB setup config

```
CollectionsTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: collection
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: collection
        KeyType: HASH
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    TableName: ${self:custom.collectionsTableName}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't demonstrated that there are no items in the table. Are you seeing that "Item count" of 0 and thinking it's timely? Notice under the Item Summary header is says the count is only updated every 6 hours. Try hitting the "Get live item count" button and I bet you'll see some items.

Why isn't the item count continuously maintained? Because it's a large distributed database which can store many trillions of items. Getting a live item count isn't always a lightweight process.

Comment: Gotta check. Thanks. Haven’t seen that. I’ve already removed the whole stack to check if creation of a new one fixes the problem

Comment: Well. It works. I was checking the result by calling another function. Interestingly it was totally messed up and had no chance to return a correct value due to the condition

Comment: Clicking on the "Get live count" did return the correct value